# Single ended to differential driver low-pass filter

Tags: adc, differential, low-pass

I am taking a single-ended source, using a SN75ALS191 driver to convert it to a differential signal. This differential signal will travel over twisted pair cabling several hundred feet, to a single terminated input. The single-ended source signal will have a maximum frequency of 8MHz. The SN75ALS191 driver has a minimum rise time of 3.5nS, so ~285MHz.

I am not familiar with differential signal transmission, but my initial thought is to use a filter right at the output of the SN75ALS191 to limit the rise time to say 3x 8MHz. I would perhaps just use an LCL filter (Chebyshev) as shown below. Of course, I could change the filter type/order to have a better response, but they would all be referenced to my driver's ground. (The values and type of filter depend on the cable type/impendence/etc, this is not what my question is about - designing the filter w/ values)

[image: 3rd Order chebyshev filter ref'd to common ground]

This would work I think, since the driver is still referenced with it's common-mode to ground, so it should effectively still slow down the rise time leaving the board. However, I see most app notes that mention filtering, don't reference the filter to the driver ground, but instead, the out+ to out- as shown below. Does my filter above, not work? Or why is the below filter the better choice?

[image: Analog Devices - Understanding and Designing Differential Filters for Communications Systems]

I do see some info on other appnotes, shown below, that seem to show an RC filter drawn like mine.

[image: Analog Devices - ADC Driving: Driving Differential ADCs]

Comment: Specifically, what are you trying to achieve and what is the end of wire line termination? You say what you propose to do but not why.

Comment: @Andyaka The reason for me filtering is to help reduce EMI on the long length of cabling. (With single-ended signaling this would be required) Since I don't have a lot of differential experience, is this not a valid reason? I know that diff signals tend to cancel out more, so maybe I am being too cautious? It is terminated with a termination resistor typically, and RC other times.

Comment: The trouble is that with your filter design you are going to have big resonances due to lack of driver series resistance and that is the reason why most drivers limit slew rate with resistors and capacitors (as per the left side of your middle picture. Maybe, if you can use a simulator you will see what I mean.

Comment: @Andyaka Nope, I totally understand what you mean. Unfortunately, that SN75ALS191 chip doesn't say what it's drive impedance is to know what R I would need... So, as long as I handle the resonance issue using a series R in there, then my filter method is OK (I could always just change it to an RC like in the bottom image)? Still don't know what they don't tie the caps to ground, and instead to each other.

Comment: They don't tie 2 caps to ground in order to minimize the potential skew in the two signals when caps to ground are used. I fewer cap means one less tolerance to worry about and slightly less potential skew between timings on the differential pair. I'd use two resistors (circa 50 ohm and 1% or better) from the 191 outputs and a common capacitor to restrict slew rate (as per what you see in the middle diagram).

Comment: @Andyaka Ahhh that makes sense, totally explains why they do it that way. Presumably I could still do the LCL filter, just having the series R in front right? Not sure if that's what you meant or not

Comment: The inductor might help reduce EMI a bit but it may cause increased skew and act to make EMI worse because of that skew not allowing normal differential signals to cancel more equally. It's difficult to be precise. The middle diagram - where did it come from?

Comment: @Andyaka Analog Devices AN-1364,,,,,, To clarify, my last comment meant to do an LCL as I drew, but have a single cap between each other and not to gnd, then add series R.

Comment: I need a hyper link to that document dude

Comment: @Andyaka https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/AN-1364.pdf